# Handling shopping cart features in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've recently made adding and deleting from cart buttons and handle them in PHP but I want a div to be "added" when a user clicks on "add to cart" and when a user clicks on "remove from cart" the div disappears.

How do I implement this if I send addToCart over POST, using this form:

```
<form class="cartOperations" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

<input type="submit" class="add-to-cart" name="removeFromCart" value="REMOVE">
<input type="submit" class="add-to-cart" name="addToCart" value="ADD TO BAG">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['addToCart'])) {
    $id = $_POST['productId'];
    if (!isset($_SESSION['PRODUCTS']))
        $_SESSION['PRODUCTS'] = array();
    $_SESSION['PRODUCTS'][] = $id; // shorthand for array_push // array_push($_SESSION['PRODUCTS'], $id);
} elseif (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['removeFromCart'])) {
    $id = $_POST['productId'];
    $key = array_search($id, $_SESSION['PRODUCTS']);
    if ($key !== false) {
        unset($_SESSION['PRODUCTS'][$key]);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Answer: Use Javascript method `window.setTimeout`. Advices: Use `short_open_tags` with care as they are off by default. Also care for code injection through `PHP_SELF`.

Answer (score 0):

You need use ajax. Like this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="delProductFromCart(id);" class="add-to-cart" name="removeFromCart" value="REMOVE">
```

Set id in php code.

in javascript set

```
function delProductFromCart(priceid, url) {
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "?ajax&delproductid="+priceid
      })
      .done(function( html ) {
          $(".block-cart-header").html( html );
          $(".block-cart-header").effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
          if (url!=undefined) { window.location = url; }
        });
}
```

or

```
function addDealToCart(priceid) {
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "?ajax&dealid="+priceid
      })
      .done(function( html ) {
          $(".block-cart-header").html( html );
          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast", function(){$(".block-cart-header").effect("highlight", {}, 1000); });
        });
```

And use $_SESSION for data storage NO good idea. Use php and storage in DB.

Comment: why did you use GET ? I want a POST request

Comment: @SafiNajjar change GET to POST ??

Comment: so how to deal with url if post ?

Answer (score 0):

This concept is called **Flash Messages**.

Please [read articles on Google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+flash+message). There are plenty of information on the subject. Many frameworks even have a documented solution for this. See [how it's done in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages) for example.